# How to make a batch file run in vscode terminal

Tags: powershell, batch-file, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to make a batch file that opens a virtual enviroment inside vscode. So far the code looks like this :

```
if NOT exist ./env (
    pip3 install virtualenv 
    virtualenv env
)
.\env\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

The if statement works as expected but the command after that does not. However when I run the program in the default terminal for windows, it works as expected.

**Edit:** I know this is probably not the best way to write the program but I'm new to batch and it works so I'm happy with it for now.

**Edit 2:** Let me try to better explain what the problem is. I when I run the program in a normal terminal it works just fine. The problem is that I use the terminal in vscode. If I try to just run a normal command in the terminal it says the command was not found (typing the name of the file). When I use the code runner extension it runs the first lines correctly but does not activate the virtual environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing batch files and powershell.  Those are two separate things.  Batch files suffix can be either `.bat` or `.cmd`.  The powershell files end usually with `.ps1`.

Batch files are using the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`.  Powershell is using the `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  As you can see those are two different interpreters.

If you need to run a `.ps1` file that is a powershell script you need to run it in powershell **not** a `.bat` file!

To execute your script you need to execute it like this:

`& 'C:\env\Scripts\activate.ps1'`

If you run it at powershell your if condition will not work anymore.  You need to do something like this:

```
$PipArgs = @('install', 'virtualenv') 
if(Test-Path -PathType leaf "C:\env"){
    & 'pip3' $PipArgs
    & 'virtualenv' 'env'
}
```

Comment: This worked and only left one problem which I solved. For those wondering how to run a powershell program in the vscode editor add ./ to the file. For example "./test" if the file is called test.ps1 Thank you so much for the help